# How do I type a single tilde (~) on a French keyboard

Tags: keyboard-layout, keymap

I am a Brit working on Unix in a French company - I am more or less used to the French keyboard now, but one problem I still have is typing a tilde (~).

The best I can do is either:

> <kbd>Alt-Gr</kbd><kbd>é</kbd><kbd>é</kbd>

which gives me 2 tildes, or

> <kbd>Alt-Gr</kbd><kbd>é</kbd><kbd>space</kbd>

which gives me one. Is there a quicker way? I know it's not a big thing but it drives me crazy!

I am on Windows XP (version française!) but spend most of my time using Putty to talk to Red Hat boxen.

Rich

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can maybe use [Autohotkey](http://www.autohotkey.com/) to remap it to a different key combo, but I haven't tried AHK with international keyboard layouts.

They key combos you are using are the correct ones on a french KB, unfortunately.

**Edit:**

FYI, you need to hit a space after the initial key combo because of the use of tildes over letters in French.  If you hit a key (like e or a) after the <kbd>Alt-Gr</kbd><kbd>é</kbd> then it will add that letter with the tilde over it.

Comment: I'm quite happy pressing Alt-Gr, but I'm surprised there's no way to get it with just two keypresses like on an English keyboard.

Comment: See my edit - it's because of the use of accents in French.

Comment: I've just realised that I can press Alt-Gr+é to get the tilde, and then straight away type Shift-: to get the forward slash, and that works fine, so it's the same number of keystrokes as on a English keyboard, just different ones :)

Answer (score 3):

For ~ on a French Canadian keyboard, type Alt+ç

Comment: That is correct! Not sure if it's the right place to ask, but do you know how to put it on the n to get ñ using that same layout? (My Google search led me here) I'm on Mac OS for what it's worth. :)

Answer (score 0):

You could just put XP in English mode :)

http://www.microsoft.com/resources/documentation/windows/xp/all/proddocs/en-us/input_kbd_add_language.mspx?mfr=true

Comment: ...except that won't correct the issue, since he still has a french keyboard.  See http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Keyboard_layout

Comment: practically You are not even trying to help him

Comment: This isn't unreasonable: if you're very familiar with the UK keyboard layout, change the keyboard interpretation to UK and try not to look down at the (now wrong) keycaps.

Comment: It seems like a solution that would cause more issues than it fixed, since he only wants to save one keystroke when he types a tilde, not remap his entire keyboard.

Comment: He states that he is "more or less" used to the French keyboard, and I assume he is familiar with the UK/US layout more. Most people I know aren't very familiar with the language options in XP, so I threw this out there for him if he'd rather use a US layout.

Comment: @Garrett - understood!  I edited your answer so I could remove my downvote.

Answer (score 0):

- You could use a 3rd party software called Virtual Keyboard . Here is the link http://www.virtual-keyboard.com/
- Another software , Hot Virtual Keyboard . Go here http://hot-virtual-keyboard.com/
- An Online keyboard, might come in handy for others, http://www.gate2home.com/?language=en&sec=2

Answer (score 0):

`AutoHotkey v2.0.11`:

```
!é::  ; alt+2 = tilde
{
    SendText "~"
}
```

This sets `alt+é` to just enter `~` while preserving `altGr+é` functionality for building accented characters. I personally need this to be able to access `~` directly in normal mode in `Vim`.

Answer (score -1):

I've just figured it on mac keyboard AZERTY belgian running emulated linux. Combination of Shift+Option+m followed by space outputs ~

Comment: The question contains a three-key sequence and asks for a quicker way — so you post a four-key answer?

Comment: Yes, you are wrong. Because three key combination is just enough and followed by "n" outputs ñ as in "ninño" 